# Deleting Cloned Elastic Beanstalk Environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I had to clone an elastic beanstalk environment to make changes to some of the server code. However, we have decided to not implement said changes just yet.

I now want to delete the cloned EB env, but am worried that it may delete the resources associated with the initial deployment. Do I need to be worried about this? Or will the cloned environment delete the original environments resources.

Comment: When cloning an existing environment, Elastic Beanstalk creates a copy of any AWS resource associated with the original environment.

Comment: @ArpitJain I can confirm that this isn't the case in my situation. However we used a nested CFN deployment for this application, so that may be the reason there is not a complete 1-to-1 replication of resources.

Comment: I commented here only after reading at the AWS docs. Please read this AWS docs if this might help you:- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.clone.html